# Error: Cannot perform an aggregate function SQL

Tags: sql

1.) I am getting an error for using SUM function in SQL is there a possible way to fix this, I tried searching the internet, but most of the examples are for single column.

```
SELECT    
    r.WorkOrderBatch,
    wo.ProductCode,
    wo.WorkOrderQty,
    Convert(DATE,wo.StartDate),
    wo.CurrentStatus,
```

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: In a glance, the error maybe because of `SUM(COUNT(...))`. It should be `SUM()` only, that sum is enough for count purpose

Comment: remove the null in the sum statement set it to 0 and maybe the count too. you will sum up the 1s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line:

`SUM(COUNT(CASE r.IsTestPass WHEN 1 THEN NULL ELSE 1 END)) AS FailedQty`

With

`SUM(CASE r.IsTestPass WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS FailedQty`

rest everything looks good

Comment: Thanks that fixed the error my data looks something like this.    
ABC 102 50 2018-04-10 Closed Fill         50 1
ABC 102 50 2018-04-10 Closed Fumb 36 1
ABC 102 50 2018-04-10 Closed Fumb 14 0